# How to use preg_match_all regex for HTML when HTML is in 1 row?

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match-all

When I am using the code formatted, it works correctly:

Regex

```
\<\/a\>\ \:\ (.+)\<\/div\>
```

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div> <a href="#"><strong>1</strong></a> : test1</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div> <a href="#"><strong>2</strong></a> : test2</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div> <a href="#"><strong>3</strong></a> : test3</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/tJtdNOyVdntUUZbV)

Using preg_match_all with the above, I get:

```
Array
(
    [0] => test1
    [1] => test2
    [2] => test3
)
```

But when I use not formatted code, the regex only takes the last instead `</div>` of create multiple parts when using `preg_match_all`:

Regex

```
\<\/a\>\ \:\ (.+)\<\/div\>
```

HTML

```
<ul> <li> <div> <a href="#"><strong>1</strong></a> : test1 </div> </li> <li> <div> <a href="#"><strong>2</strong></a> : test2 </div> </li> <li> <div> <a href="#"><strong>3</strong></a> : test3 </div> </li> </ul>
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Yg-ov9xF6-pd_GNF)

But when using this, I get array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => test1 </div> </li> <li> <div> <a href="#"><strong>2</strong></a> : test2 </div> </li> <li> <div> <a href="#"><strong>3</strong></a> : test3 
)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `\<\/a\>\ \:\ (.+?)\<\/div\>`

Comment: +1 for nicely formatted question :D

Comment: You should not use regex for parsing HTML at all.

Comment: @Teejay Please also name your alternative way.

Comment: @Bondye You should use some HTML parser, there are plenty out there. Regex are not specialized for dyck languages (parentheses balance etc), although some regex flavours have base support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the `+` quantifier is greedy, meaning (loosely) that it will match as much as it can while the regex returns a overall match.

For example, `.+</div>` will match `abc</div>efg` in `abc</div>efg</div>`: each character in the `</div>` string can be matched by the dot `.` and the greedy quantifier eats up as much as possible.

What you want to do is either make it lazy, so that it matches the least amount possible, with `+?`:

```
</a> : (.+?)</div>
```

Or, if you know your text can't contain `<`, use `[^<]` (ie anything except a `<`) instead of a `.`: that way `[^<]+` can't eat up `</div>`:

```
</a> : ([^<]+)</div>
```

Your regex was previously working because the dot `.` by default doesn't match newlines. On a side note, no need to escape everything in your regex...

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
<?php

$string = '<ul> <li> <div> <a href="#"><strong>1</strong></a> : test1 </div> </li> <li> <div> <a href="#"><strong>2</strong></a> : test2 </div> </li> <li> <div> <a href="#"><strong>3</strong></a> : test3 </div> </li> </ul>';
$pattern = '#</a>\s*:\s*(.+?)</div>#';
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $out);

print_r($out);
?>
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  : test1 
            [1] =>  : test2 
            [2] =>  : test3 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => test1 
            [1] => test2 
            [2] => test3 
        )

)
```

The white space might be changed (space or tab) therefore, its better to use `\s` to match all white spaces even (\n or \r)

Answer (score 0):

```
</a>\s?+:\s?+(.*?)\s?+</div>
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/1wm9xesOcm7C5gzU)

Comment: I read that the `?` sign is for lazy...? Could you tell me what that means?

Comment: @Tuga: not when it is following a quantifier instead of a character, no. See [this link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) for more details. Also in your answer there really is no need for the `?` in any of the `\s+?`. `\s+?(.*?)` will make the `\s` match only one space even if there are multiple.

Comment: Match any single character «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»

Comment: The `+` in `\s+?</div>` will also make your regex fail if there aren't any spaces between the text and the closing div: see [here](http://regex101.com/r/uA2tU0) for a `</a> : foobar</div>` example.

Comment: `\s?+` does not do what you think, it makes the `?` quantifier a possessive one. If you want to say "zero or more", you need to use the `*` quantifier: `</a>\s*:\s*(.*?)\s*</div>`